# How to subscript +, -, _, and other arithmetic symbols in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, syntax-error

Previous questions on subscripts in R (specifically relating to text in ggplot/annotate/geo arguments) don't quite touch on this issue.

Say I want to have a subscript "+", like

$\Sigma_+$

If I do something like

```
scale_colour_manual(values = c('red' = 'red','blue' = 'blue'),name = '', 
                  labels = expression(P[+] - P[-] == P[w])
```

We get an error similar to:

```
Error: unexpected ']' in:
"scale_colour_manual(values = c('red' = 'red','blue' = 'blue'),name = '', 
labels = expression(P[+]"
```

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but keep the question part in your question, and move the answer part to the answer box below. :-)

Comment: Also, please consider expanding your question + answer into a fully worked example that sets up some example data (e.g. using one of R's built-in datasets) and shows all the code needed to actually apply the solution. It will be much more useful to future users if they can copy-paste your example code and immediately see that the solution works.

Answer (score 1):

I think that R thinks that the + is acting as a arithematic operator, and adding two non-numbers "[" and "]".

The solution is to put make the subscript a character string. I think that some people may forget that this is a possibility.

```
scale_colour_manual(values = c('red' = 'red','blue' = 'blue'),name = '', 
                  labels = expression(P["+"] - P["-"] == P[w])
```